# Geolocate a PostGIS database

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, postgis, qgis

I have a PostGIS database with addresses (street with number, city, state) and fields for lat and long as well as geometry. I geolocated some of the addresses before bringing into PostGIS but since have added other addresses. How do I geolocate these addresses.

FWIW they are all in the same city, but I have city and state fields.

A major problem will be many of the addresses won't exist or will have different coordinates because the addresses are from 100 or more years ago. I know I'll have to do some of the addresses manually using overlay maps from the period.

I see plenty of suggestions on how to geolocate CSV files, but not using directly from QGIS or pgAdmin!

The database is managed in Ruby on Rails if that's a better way to tackle this.

Comment: if you have lat long, just create the geometry object as a point, not sure what is the problem

Comment: I don't have lat long for some of the addresses.

Comment: Then you ask the wrong  question.  If you have a layer for state city you can geolocate aprox, but you probably will need do something by hand

Comment: I have address, city and state fields; and I want to geolocate and fill the lat and long fields. This is in a PostGIS database.

Comment: beside your address, what layers you have in Postgis?

Comment: I have layers on QGIS, but not in PostGIS AFAIK. I have other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Tiger Geocoder](http://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html#Tiger_Geocoder), which only works for U.S. addresses. Install it with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Then load the data for your State(s), and the use [Geocode](http://postgis.net/docs/Geocode.html) to approximate the geometry. For historic addresses, perhaps you can request historic TIGER data from [these guys](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) (although I have no idea if they actually have digitized census data from 100 years ago).

---

Otherwise, if you know Python, there are a range of services you can use with [geopy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy) to geocode locations from addresses.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to get my head around this. I ran your installation.

From your link I gather I need to write SQL to do what I want. I'll give it a go.

Comment: I followed Mike T's suggestion and found  National Historical Geographic Information System (NHGIS),  http://nhgis.org.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you Mike T, your answer got me looking with clearer understanding of what I needed. I followed http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder describing using the Ruby geocoder gem which I was able to integrate into my Rails project.

I understand that I answered a different question than I asked. I haven't completely done this, but I think it will be easier than what I was thinking of. I may have to force it for each address, but I don't have that many.